# Function to convert number into words?

Tags: abap

is there a function in abap can convert digit to word?

example:
**100** will be converted into **one hundred** or **200** will be converted into **two hundred**

example:
**300** will be converted into **tree hundred** or **400** will be converted into **four hundred**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a standard function module called `SPELL_AMOUNT` that does this.

Some info [here](http://www.se80.co.uk/sapfms/s/spel/spell_amount.htm). It's also in the [ABAP FAQ](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/FAQ#FAQ-HowcanIconvertnumeralsintothecorrespondingtext%3F) on SDN.